# Property id does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: typescript, redux, reducers

I'm trying to do a `.map` function into a state array in Redux with Typescript, the problem is that it's throwing an error

> [ts] Property 'id' does not exist on type 'never'

in the `landing.id` if statement, since its an array of objects the code makes sense for me but seems that I'm missing something there

```
export default function landingReducer (state = [], action) {
switch(action.type) {
  case ActionTypes.ADD_LANDING:
    return [...state, action.landing]
  case ActionTypes.EDIT_LANDING:
    return state.map(landing => {
      if (action.landing.id == landing.id) {
        return landing;
      }
    })
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably due to types missing for the `state` and/or `action` arguments. Try this code that should work with TypeScript 2.4+, inspired by this [article](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/07/24/redux-action-pattern-typescript/):

```js
interface Landing {
    id: any;
}

enum ActionTypes {
    ADD_LANDING  = "ADD_LANDING",
    EDIT_LANDING = "EDIT_LANDING",
    OTHER_ACTION = "__any_other_action_type__"
}

interface AddLandingAction {
    type: ActionTypes.ADD_LANDING;
    landing: Landing;
}

interface EditLandingAction {
    type: ActionTypes.EDIT_LANDING;
    landing: Landing;
}

type LandingAction =
    | AddLandingAction
    | EditLandingAction;

function landingReducer(state: Landing[], action: LandingAction) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ActionTypes.ADD_LANDING:
            return [...state, action.landing]

        case ActionTypes.EDIT_LANDING:
            return state.map(landing => {
                if (action.landing.id === landing.id) {
                    return landing;
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing brackets and other necessary imports, which makes it difficult for someone else to quickly [reproduce and diagnose](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

That being said, TypeScript infers the `state` parameter as the type of an empty array literal `[]`, which is considered to be `never[]`, meaning it will always be empty.  So the `map` function doesn't work because `landing` is being inferred as being an impossible value (there are no valid values of type `never`).

If you want to fix it, you should tell TypeScript what kind of array `state` is likely to be.  The quick fix is to make it an array of `any`:

```
... function landingReducer (state: any[] = [], action) ...
```

Ideally, you should add more specific types to your parameters so that TypeScript can help you catch errors (how do you know that `action` has a `type` property?).

Hope that helps; good luck!